# File location, not the same as folder path. Video file do not play. Using Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, files-folders

- Edition   Windows 10 Pro
- Version   21H2
- Installed on  ‎6/‎15/‎2022
- OS build  19044.2006
- Experience    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0
- Secondary hard drive "D:"  the one with the issue.

**Issue:**
Due to the video file location being incorrect, video files are not playing.

**Example:**
When looking at the properties of bad files.

Location:  `\\?\D:\Other Games\123.mp4`  ← The extra slash are causing issues.

Folder path:  `D:\Other Games\ 123.mp4`

**Request:**
Is there any way to modify the location to be the same as the folder path? I have over 250 GB of these files.

Below are the images of the same file:

[image: Properties image of Location]

[image: Properties image of Folder Path]

[image: More Info]

Comment: What is giving you the bad folder path?  What are those screenshots from?

Comment: Those screenshots are of the properties of a video file. The file does not play in VLC . The "\\?\D:" is causing the error and I just need help to make it just "D:\" and remove the slashes and question mark before "D:\".  Thanks

Comment: Properties as reported by what, though?  Is that what you get when you right-click on the file and choose Properties?  Or some other tool reporting it?  Need to know what it is that is presenting that path.

Comment: Yes, by right-clicking the file and looking at its properties.

Comment: @gamerboy Are you using the latest version of VLC (3.0.17.4 at the time of writing)? They might have fixed the issue since it was reported back in the year 2010 or so.

Comment: Yes I am using updated VLC. I even tried MPC-HC 1.9.23. This is the error . Your input can't be opened: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file://?/D%3A/Other%20Games/.....

Comment: @gamerboy 1) How do you try to open the file? Is it by double-clicking it in File Explorer, or by opening it from within VLC? 2) Do you have a complete and reliable backup of the contents of drive D:?

Comment: @gamerboy You might want to google for "VLC is unable to open the MRL" and see if any of those results help.

Comment: Thanks, but we got the issue solved. It was caused by long folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the text of your question, you only show a single backslash; the screenshot shows a **double** backslash, as in [Microsoft's implementation of the UNC path convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats), "A server or host name, which is prefaced by \\." For some reason Windows considers the D: drive to be on a remote server.

Where are these files actually located? On a drive in the PC? On a remote server or NAS? If on a remote device, try making a shortcut to the device, e.g. \MY_NAS, or \MY_NAS"Other Games".

Another possibility is that the space in the folder *Other Games* is causing issues on the server. Try changing the folder to *OtherGames* to avoid need for quotes.

*Footnote:* Questioner has determined it *is* a folder name issue, due to *length* of total file path; and the hint to remove space helped resolve issue by showing some files were visible in shortened path. Kudos to questioner for letting others know.

Comment: The appearance of the single backslash was a result of SU treating the first backslash as an escape for the second backslash. I fixed the display of it in the question; the problem remains in your answer, e.g. at `\\MY_NAS`.

Comment: I have added a new image, This is on a PC hard drive in my pc.

Answer (score 0):

DrMoishe Pippik, your suggestion to rename the folder helped resolve the issue.

> It was caused by a very long folder name and video name. After renaming the folder to something shorter, all the videos in the folder now work.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post thank you as an answer.

Comment: Just ticking the answer is considered thanks enough.